# Rotate a quaternion / Change the axis it rotates around

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, geometry, quaternions

Conceptually a quaternion can store the rotation around an axis by some degree.
Now, what is the numerically most robust and least calculation intensive way to rotate the axis?

For example when i have a quaternion, which rotates 90 degrees around the y-axis and i want those 90 degrees to be applied to some other arbitrary axis, described by a normalized vector.

EDIT: Since this also came up i added an answer on how to correctly change the axis a quaternion rotates around with another quaternion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what your actual goal is by doing what you describe.

In order to actually keep the angle but change the axis you would use [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html), alter the axis and then pass it back into [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html)

like e.g.

```
Quaternion someRotation;

someRotation.ToAngleAxis(out var angle, out var axis);

var newAxis = Vector3.up;
var newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, new axis);
```

---

Or you rotate an existing `Quaternion` by another one using [`*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) like

```
Quaternion newRotation = someRotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
```

which would take the existing rotation and rotate it by 90° around the X axis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i wasn't aware of `ToAngleAxis`. The first solution solves the problem i described. But the second one isn't correct, since it won't "rotate" the first quaternions axis, but just apply the rotation around the x-axis first and then `someRotation` afterward, `someRotation` still being on it's own axis.

Comment: The second part does exactly what I say: It rotates an existing rotation. Like adding an additional rotation to the already existing one ;) See [`Quaternion` operator `*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html). Obviously it doesn't edit the existing rotations but returns a new one as the result of combining both rotations ;)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the first and second solution won't produce the same result. But this conversation seems to be lacking solid terms to describe the things we want to say. Cause for me "rotating a quaternion" means changing its axis of rotation and not adding just another one on top, but since i kinda made up this term it probably makes no sense to further discuss this.

Comment: There are several posts around this, I've posted something I found that worked for me in this q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040325/unity-c-sharp-quaternion-swap-y-with-z-axis/74531976#74531976

Answer (score 3):

@derHugo's solution, solves the problem i initially asked, but the seconds part of his answer isn't doing what he seemed to be describing. To rotate a quaternions axis of rotation with another quaternion you would need to apply the rotations differently.

E.g. you have a quaternion yQuaternion, which rotates 90° around the y-axis and want to rotate, it's rotation axis by 90° around the x-axis (which would result in a quaternion rotating 90° around the z-axis) you'd have to do the following.

```
// The quaternion, we want to "rotate"
var yQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f, 0f);
// The quaternion we want to rotate by.
var xQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f);

var result = xQuaternion * yRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(xQuaternion);
```

What happens here is that we first rotate backwards to our desired axis, then apply the rotation we want to use and then revert the rotation we initally applied.

NOTE: I'm quit sure, that saying "rotate a quaternion" isn't a valid term when talking about this quaternion operations.